# Regex to parse log data not capturing all groups

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex to parse the "Structured Data" section of a RFC5424 log file. I have a working regex, but I can't see why it doesn't return each of the `key=value` pairs.

The basic format of the data is as follows -

`[ELEMENT-ID KEY="VALUE"]`

There can be multiple key/value pairs, and there can also be multiple elements.
The regex and test data i'm using is as follows -

`(\[\S+(\s[^=]+="[^"]*")+\])+`

`[one var="[x] yz" var2="test"] Log Message`

Basically, I'm looking for multiple `[]` sections next to each other. Each section contains non space, followed by one or more `\sKEY="VALUE"` entries.

When running this it seems to match fine, but the only groups returned are the full match, and the last `key=value` pair. As far as I can see, it must be using central capture group to match both `key=value` pairs, so I don't see why both aren't returned in the capture list.

Comment: The group is overwritten each time, see https://regex101.com/r/ycIcO0/1/. Either use `\G` when it is supported or use two expressions.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/ycIcO0/2/